# Does Express or Node return the app/server object as part of the request object?

Tags: node.js, express

I am reviewing an older node project ([Typhoon blog engine](https://github.com/cjoudrey/typhoon)).

In the route definition module, there are [several](https://github.com/cjoudrey/typhoon/blob/master/src/typhoon/routes/article.js#L47) [functions](https://github.com/cjoudrey/typhoon/blob/master/src/typhoon/routes/article.js#L72) [that use](https://github.com/cjoudrey/typhoon/blob/master/src/typhoon/routes/article.js#L115) the statement `req.app.{something}` where `{something}` is a function based off of the `app` object (i.e. the object created from the deprecated `express.createServer()` or the non-deprecated `express()`).

I cant find any documentation for express or node that state this object would normally be attached to the `request` object. Nor do I see anywhere in the project I am reviewing where `req.app` is explicitly defined.

So is the presence of `req.app` deprecated behavior for node or express? or is there some deeper magic afoot that I have missed? How is it being done in this [project](https://github.com/cjoudrey/typhoon)?

---

**edit**

When searching the source, I found the following. I still don't see where it is defined, but it does appear to be used in the express `request` module.

```
grep -i -r --exclude-dir=*examples --exclude-dir=*test 'this\.app' ./express
./express/lib/request.js:  var trustProxy = this.app.get('trust proxy');
./express/lib/request.js:  var trustProxy = this.app.get('trust proxy');
./express/lib/request.js:  var offset = this.app.get('subdomain offset');
./express/lib/request.js:  var trustProxy = this.app.get('trust proxy');
./express/lib/response.js:  var app = this.app;


grep -i -r --exclude-dir=*examples --exclude-dir=*test 'app =' ./express
./express/lib/application.js:var app = exports = module.exports = {};
./express/lib/application.js:  if (fn.handle && fn.set) mount_app = fn;
./express/lib/application.js: *      , app = express();
./express/lib/response.js:  var app = this.app;
./express/lib/response.js:    , app = req.app;
./express/lib/express.js:  var app = function(req, res, next) {
./express/support/app.js:var app = express()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is defined in express/lib/express.js ~line 33:

```
function createApplication() {
  var app = connect();
  utils.merge(app, proto);
  app.request = { __proto__: req, app: app };
  app.response = { __proto__: res, app: app };
  app.init();
 return app;
```

}